# how can I automatically run my C# program after a reset on Windows CE?

Tags: c#, windows-ce, autorun

How can I automatically run my C# program after hard-reset or soft-reset on Windows CE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your applications .reg file, add the following:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\init]
>           "Launch50"="PlatformStartup.exe"
>           "Depend50"=hex:14,00,1E,00

Source - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446914.aspx

Hope that helps!

Comment: Except that this will fail for a C# app. http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/04/15/AutolaunchingCFAppsWithTheHKLMInitRegistryKey.aspx

Comment: And you have it depending on the entries at 20 and 30, yet you don't know what those entries are.  Again a bad, or at least incomplete, recommendation

Comment: Oh, and launching this way requires that your app calls the SignalStarted API with the index passed in to you.  I doubt his app does that, so anything after entry 50 will never get launched.

Answer (score 1):

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\init] will not launch your C# app! You should read that article Chris Tacke gave [link](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/04/15/AutolaunchingCFAppsWithTheHKLMInitRegistryKey.aspx) to.

There is also some ready solutions like [AutoLaunch](http://www.learningce.com/Downloads/796.aspx), that you can include in your OS image as a subproject. If you choose this solution, make sure that you have the APIs it is waiting for (check IsNetworkReady()) or it will hang there forever.